# Как обработать событие нажатия клавиш вне окна на Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity3d, keydown

Мне нужно, чтобы отлавливало `KeyDown` и `KeyUp`, когда окно неактивно. Делаю приложение в `Unity`, соответственно, скрипт пишу на `C#`. Нужно какое-то решение.

Comment: Если Windows, то keyboard hook через WinAPI

Comment: Можно поподробнее? Как мне это реализовать в скрипте.

Comment: Так же как в любом другом приложении для Windows, минус а том что так как вы будете отслеживать клавиатуру, антивирус может убить игру как вируса, клавиатурного шпиона.

Comment: Я, к сожалению, не работал с WinAPI.

Comment: Помогите мне пожалуйста написать рабочий скрипт, я пробовал, но не получилось.

Comment: Написать для вас клавиатурного шпиона? Нет, спасибо.